# Is it even possible Generic Deserialize function that return null if input is null

Tags: c#, generics

In below code i can't return null, that will result in error ( T can be non-Nullable value type)

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] serializedData) 
    {
        //if (serializedData == null) { return null; } //// error 

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        memoryStream.Write(serializedData, 0, serializedData.Length);

        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
```

By adding default(T) will fix null issue

```
if (serializedData == null) { return default(T); }
```

but that will return default value (false for bool etc..)  .. is any other way we can do this ?

Comment: well, what do you expect an `int` to be if there is no data? Value-types can´t be `null`. What you want is a `Nullable<int>`, or just `int?`.

Comment: what would be your input here?

Comment: you can add some constraint to `T` if you need. `where T : Class` to force a reference type (thus, nullable, at least in C# 7- )

Comment: @HimBromBeere for value type return Nullable<Type> , eg Nullable<int>

Comment: @Pac0 but then i have to make multiple function for ref , value types etc..

Comment: Then just define `T` to be `Nullable<int>`. Your method can´t return both, a `T` and a `Nullable<T>`. So call your method using `DeSerialize<int?>(...)`.

Comment: you can define a flag and return that instead of null and your caller would understand that probably.

Comment: Important bit of advice: don't use `BinaryFormatter` unless you're only using it within the context of an app-domain or IPC/RPC between two app-domains that will always be running the exact same assemblies. It is **incredibly** brittle and hates versioning. It also isn't very efficient in either CPU or data size.

Comment: What's the thinking behind creating the memory stream, writing the array to it and re-winding, rather than just passing the array to the stream's constructor?

Comment: @MarcGravell ,@Damien_The_Unbeliever , this is existing code in old system. i can have a look on both issues . thanks for the advice